# How to create link libraries?

Tags: navigation

Is there a way around to build link library repository on a drupal site, so that there can be one place to edit the links and changes will reflect in the instances used else where (like body field of a content type)

Any starting pointers?

Comment: There's a module called Linkchecker. It doesn't do exactly what you're looking for. But I think it's a good alternative for what you're trying to achieve perhaps. Scanning nodes and str replacing the content will probably be a bit expensive on the server resources, but you could write something custom I suppose.

Comment: looks like the mentioned module can be good reference for building custom one, thanks @Beebee :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer that exact question, but to solve that problem we typically use the [Linkit](https://drupal.org/project/linkit) module.

This will add an additional button to the WYSIWYG for creating links.  When you click it, you get a popup which lets you choose a link (somewhat similar to the entity reference autocomplete widget), and also set link options.

It will then build a link in the markup using a token.  When the page is rendered, the token gets replaced with the path alias for what you selected.  So, if the path for a node changes, the token replacement will take care of fixing everything.

Comment: thanks! I will a try, but it looks too close to what we need, thanks again :)

Comment: Hi I have installed Linkit module on my local.But it doesnt seem to work with CKEditor module. I mean the button is not appearing on the editor

Comment: @SanyaGulati Did you set permissions properly, and add it to the button set via the profile?  I am using it with the WYSIWYG module with CKEditor.

Answer (score 0):

Found one more interesting module as [Word Link](https://drupal.org/project/word_link).